# Do passkeys on iCloud Keychain ever exist unencrypted outside the secure enclave?

Tags: keychain, webauthn, icloud

Regarding [Apple's beta feature of storing WebAuthn passkeys in the iCloud Keychain](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10106/), does anybody know if the unencrypted passkeys ever leave the secure enclave, and get stored in RAM or anything?

With traditional WebAuthn on a Yubikey or similar device, my understanding is that the private key never leaves the Yubikey, that the requester just inputs the ID of the passkey they'd like to use and supplies a challenge to sign to the Yubikey, and the Yubikey spits out the signed challenge. That way, even if an attacker has root access to your machine, they *still* can't get that passkey.

I'm hoping it works a similar way for iCloud Keychain passkeys: that the encrypted passkey and the challenge are fed to the secure enclave, which then decrypts the encrypted passkey, and then uses it to sign the challenge and then spits out the result, all with the unencrypted passkey never leaving the secure enclave. But I can't find anything definitively stating this. Anyone know for sure / have sources to back it up?

Comment: I'm also looking for this. 
If the keypair is generated in Secure Enclave, there is no way to use it totally from another device. So I think passkey is saved in the icloud keychain, not using secure enclave.

Answer (score 0):

It is said, "With Passkeys, a unique digital key is generated and stored on the secure enclave of your device." in https://www.techguide.com.au/news/computers-news/apple-may-have-killed-the-password-with-the-introduction-of-passkeys-at-wwdc

But I cannot find the source from Apple.

" If the keypair is generated in Secure Enclave, there is no way to use it totally from another device. " agreed. But I hope Apple got some magic...

Comment: I don't want to sound rude, but if you read such rather slimmed down articles and not in-depth documentation, reports - you won't find this kind of information. It also seems because of that your answer does not add any useful information as all apparently.